# Should fat be prioritized over carbs for body recomposition?

Tags: body-fat

Healthy no allergies Male 30 y.o. Trying to recomposition. Lose fat and gain muscle. Current body fat 18%, goal is 13%. Protein intake is stable and maxed out as (1g/1lbs).

1. Option:  Protein 30%. Carbs 15%. Fat 55%.
2. Option:  Protein 30%. Carbs 55%. Fat 15%.

Which option will yield better and faster results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Macro split doesn’t matter. What matters is the magnitude of your deficit.

Neither of these macro distributions is better than the other for *rate of weight loss*. What matters is the size of the deficit.

Now, I *suspect* that the higher carb diet, assuming those carbs are from whole food sources, *not simple sugars*, will be a higher satiety dietary pattern than the higher fat diet. If this is the case, adherence, and thereby success, is likely to be easier on the high carb diet.

But if you matched the two calorie-for-calorie, the rate of weight loss would be the same.

Comment: Although probably fairly small, the higher carb diet will have an effect. The higher thermic effect of carbohydrates will mean that the net calorie absorption will be slightly lower, gram for gram, than than higher fats. Also, beyond fat loss, higher carb diets are better as they provide better energy for training and improve muscle building.